# Changing 8 digit number format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I am having trouble changing the format of a user input of an 8 digit number (XXXXXXXX) into this format, (XXX-XX-XXX) if I could get help with this that would be great thanks!!!

Comment: Show us what you did try and we can help you correct that.

Comment: You could use slicing together with simple concatenation. If you have no idea, what I'm talking about, I could suggest reading something like [this](http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/).